# Attribute with Image to show next to title

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes

I have created an attribute and when clicked on, I need it to show this image
next to the product title on the front end.

https://www.ukmadesweets.co.uk/pub/media/logo/stores/1/icon-echo.svg

[image: Eco button]

Could someone give me instructions on how to do this? I have some knowledge of Magento and got this far. But could use some step-by-step instructions on this as I will be adding more attributes.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As i correct understand you want to render some image depends on product attribute on PDP before images. I will share example and I hope you can fit it for your needs.

You need to create layout `catalog_product_view.xml` in your custom theme or custom module.

In module path like **app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

In theme path like **app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<\Theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.media.icons"
                   template="Acme_StackExchange::product/view/media/icon.phtml" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You can use custom block instead of `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` and add additional logic if you need. This block allows to access to current product.

Create related template

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/templates/product/view/media/icon.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $block
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php $this
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer
 */

$product  = $block->getProduct();
// example URL to media
$mediaUrl = $product->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
// or create custom block and retrieve image URL from anyone other place

?>
<?php if ($product->getData('eco_collection') === '1'): ?>
    <div>
        <img src="<?= $mediaUrl . '/logo/stores/1/icon-echo.svg' ?>" alt="">
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have put in the details above, but it doesn't seem to be showing when I enable the attribute. Have I missed something?

https://www.ukmadesweets.co.uk/eco-range-eco-midi-box-mint-imperials.html

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks   https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb7F9.png   https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEw33.png  https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6njL.png

Comment: In my example `Acme/StackExchange` it's your custom module and if you want to use the `Acme/StackExchange` name from example you need to properly register extension or use like `Magento_Catalog::product/view/media/icon.phtml` and place template into `app/design/frontend/\<Vendor>/\<\Theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/media/icon.phtml`. Also in your screen you've missed `Magento_Catalog` in layout path.